# What is causing the huge network traffic?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, traffic

I have a virtual machine hosted by Hyper-V, in a physical server provided by Hetzner.

The physical server has Windows 2008 R2 Server, and the virual machine has Windows 7 Pro 32-bit.

The virtual machine is running IIS and is accessible from outside via a dedicated IP.

My traffic is monitored by Hetzner, and sometimes I receive a notification for a huge spike in outgoing traffic (for the VM's IP), like 2 or 3 GB in an hour. But this is a test machine, and only a few people know about it.

There is absolutely no demand that justifies this volume of data transfer.

Using TCPView from Sysinternals, running on the VM, I don't see any suspicious connection.

Can the traffic be caused by a process not listed in TCPView?

Answer (score 0):

When they tell you have a spike of outgoing traffic execute the Resource Monitor of Windows 7 (using perfmon.exe) and go to the tab called Network.

There you can order your process by send bytes per second and know what is sending that traffic.
Regards